# Execution of ContinueWith when the antecedent Task is in canceled state and usage of async delegate inside of ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

The code discussed here is written in C# and executed with .netcore 3.1

I have the following piece of code, which starts a workload in the background without awaiting for it to complete (fire and forget):

```
public void StartBackgroundWork(IAsyncDisposable resource, CancellationToken token)
{
    // some background work is started in a fire and forget manner
    _ = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        
        try 
        {
            // here I perform my background work. Regardless of the outcome resource must be released as soon as possible
            // I want that cancellation requests coming from the provided cancellation token are correctly listened by this code
            // So, I pass the cancellation token everywhere
            
            await Task.Delay(1500, token);
        }
        finally 
        {
            // here I need to release the resource. Releasing this resource is important and must be done as soon as possible
            await resource.DisposeAsync();
        }       
    }, token);
}
```

There are three important points:

- the background work is started in a fire and forget manner. I'm not interested in awaiting its completion
- the provided cancellation token is important and the background work must listed to incoming cancellation requests
- the provided resource (`IAsyncDisposable`) must be released as soon as possible, regardless of the outcome of the background work. In order to release the resource a call to `DisposeAsync` is required.

The problem with this code is that the cancellation token is passed to `Task.Run` invokation. If the token is canceled **before** the execution of the async delegate starts, the async delegate is never executed and so the `finally` block is never executed. By doing so the requirement of releasing the `IAsyncDisposable` resource is not met (basically, `DisposeAsync` is never called).

The simplest way to solve this issue is **not** providing the cancellation token when `Task.Run` is invoked. That way, the async delegate is always executed and so the finally block is executed too. The code inside the async delegate listens to cancellation requests, so the requirement of cancel the execution is met too:

```
public void StartBackgroundWork(IAsyncDisposable resource, CancellationToken token)
{
    // some background work is started in a fire and forget manner
    _ = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        
        try 
        {
            // here I perform my background work. Regardless of the outcome resource must be released as soon as possible
            // I want that cancellation requests coming from the provided cancellation token are correctly listened by this code
            // So, I pass the cancellation token everywhere
            
            await Task.Delay(1500, token);
        }
        finally 
        {
            // here I need to release the resource. Releasing this resource is important and must be done as soon as possible
            await resource.DisposeAsync();
        }       
    }, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

I'm asking myself whether the release of the `IAsyncDisposable` resource should, instead, be delegated to a continuation task. The code refactored by using this approach is the following:

```
public void StartBackgroundWork(IAsyncDisposable resource, CancellationToken token)
{
    // some background work is started in a fire and forget manner
    _ = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        // here I perform my background work. Regardless of the outcome resource must be released as soon as possible
        // I want that cancellation requests coming from the provided cancellation token are correctly listened by this code
        // So, I pass the cancellation token everywhere
        
        await Task.Delay(1500, token);
    }, 
    token).ContinueWith(async _ => 
    {
        // release the IAsyncDisposable resource here, afte the completion of the antecedent task and regardless
        // of the antecedent task actual state
        await resource.DisposeAsync();
    });
}
```

I'm not really familiar with `ContinueWith` gotchas, so my questions are the following:

1. do I have the guarantee that the continuation is **always** executed, even if the cancellation token is canceled **before** the execution of the antecedent task starts ?
2. is there any issue in providing an async delegate to the invokation of `ContinueWith` ? Is the execution of the async delegate fully completed as expected ?
3. What is the best approach ? Passing `CancellationToken.None` to the invokation of `Task.Run`, or relying on the continuation by using `ContinueWith` ?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I know that using `Task.Run` is **not** the best approach in a server application (more on that can be found [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)), so there are probably much better ways of designing my overall architecture. I posted this question to better understanding the actual behavior of `ContinueWith`, because I'm not really familiar with its usage (in modern .NET code it is largely replaced by the usage of `async await`).

Comment: Quite honestly, `ContinueWith` is the legacy API, and shouldn't really be used much, if ever; if it was me, I'd lose the `token` on the `Task.Run` call, and just use `await using` (or `try`/`finally`/`await resource.DisposeAsync()` if the logic is particularly complex) **inside** the `async` lambda.

Comment: The disclaimer is indeed important here, because you are definitely doing some suspicious and code review fail things here

Comment: As a side note you don't need to pass as argument the `CancellationToken.None`. The `Task.Run` method has an overload that accepts only a single argument (the `action` delegate), which is also the most commonly used overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Theodor has a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66966472/263693); I'm just going to answer some of your other questions:

> do I have the guarantee that the continuation is always executed, even if the cancellation token is canceled before the execution of the antecedent task starts ?

`ContinueWith` will execute its delegate even of the antecedent task is already completed. In this specific case, there is no "guarantee" simply because of the nature of fire-and-forget.

> is there any issue in providing an async delegate to the invokation of ContinueWith ?

`ContinueWith` is not `async`-aware, so the return type of `ContinueWith` is surprising for most developers. Since your code discards the return type, that's not a concern here.

> Is the execution of the async delegate fully completed as expected ?

In this case, most likely, but it really depends on what "expected" means. Like all other fire-and-forget code, you can't guarantee completion. `ContinueWith` has an additional wrinkle: it executes its delegate using a `TaskScheduler`, and the default `TaskScheduler` is not `TaskScheduler.Default` but is actually `TaskScheduler.Current`. So I always recommend passing an explicit `TaskScheduler` for clarity if you really need to use `ContinueWith`.

> What is the best approach ? Passing CancellationToken.None to the invokation of Task.Run, or relying on the continuation by using ContinueWith ?

Just drop the second argument to `Task.Run`.

I'll go further than that: `Task.Run` probably shouldn't even *take* a `CancellationToken`. I have yet to see a scenario where it's useful. I suspect the `CancellationToken` part of the API was copied from `TaskFactory.StartNew` (where it *is* rarely useful), but since `Task.Run` always uses `TaskScheduler.Default`, providing a `CancellationToken` is not useful in practice.

P.S. I recently wrote a short series on the [proper solution for fire-and-forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html).

Comment: what actually is the usefullnes of async void (if any) in my code sample? I remember your book stating to avoid async void. I'm always a bit nervous about that, because of your guideline. Theodore mentioned async void in his response.

Comment: The problem with discarding tasks (as in your original code) is that all exceptions from that task are ignored. So if something unthinkable happened like `DisposeAsync` throwing, you would never know - the app would ignore it and just keep running (or trying to run). The idea behind `async void` in Theodor's answer is that if something unthinkable happened the app would crash instead of trying to run. Avoiding async void is a good general rule but this would be an exception to that general rule.

Comment: got it. Here I'm adopting a simplistic solution, to avoid the introduction of a durable queue and a backend service, which is (as you mention in your article) the cleanest approach. Probably a decent workaround can be using `Task.Run` with a top level `try catch` statement catching everything and logging. By doing so I'll have, at least, some log entries and I would avoid the usage of `async void`. That way I can avoid the app crash caused by `async void` (in a prod environment app crashes can alarm a lot of people). In this context `Task.Run` is just a way to fake a durable queue.

Comment: Basically, if I fully understood the whole history, `Task.Run` and `async void` are both a technique to have a fire and forget approach. The main difference is that unhandled exceptions with `Task.Run` are swallowed, while unhandled exceptions with `async void` will crash the entire thing. So `Task.Run` along with a top level `try catch` handling the type `Exception` seems to be a good approach.

Comment: @EnricoMassone: Neither of them were developed for fire-and-forget. `async void` was designed for event handlers, and `Task.Run` is for queueing work to the thread pool.

Comment: Anything short of a durable queue and backend service is going to be unreliable at some point. If you're OK with that, then that's your decision. E.g., having a `catch` with logging will usually work but occasionally might not log anything. If you're doing a full `try`/`catch` over the whole delegate, then using `async void` vs `async Task` doesn't make a huge difference. Personally, if I *had* to do fire-and-forget, then I would use Theodor's answer, because if an unexpected error happens, it's *better* to crash (and restart) than to try to hobble along in an unknown state.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider using the [`await using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement, that handles the asynchronous disposal of the `resource` automatically:

```
public async void StartBackgroundWork(IAsyncDisposable resource, CancellationToken token)
{
    await using var _ = resource;
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            await Task.Delay(1500, token);
        }, token);
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}
```

I also converted your fire-and-forget task to an `async void` (aka fire-and-crash) method. In case the unthinkable happens and your code has a bug, instead of the app continue running with an unobserved exception having occurred, resulting possibly to corrupted application state, the whole app will crash, forcing you to fix the bug ASAP.

But honestly creating a disposable resource in one method and disposing it in another is a smelly design. Ideally the method that created the resource should be responsible for disposing it finally.

Comment: can you please expand a little bit on the point of async void and fire and crash? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @EnricoMassone you can read about `async void` methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). Essentially an `async void` method has event handler semantics. In case of an exception it behaves the same way as an unhandled exception in an event handler: it causes the raising of either the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event, or an application-specific event like the `Application.ThreadException` in WinForms. And then the app dies.